# Facebook user_posts permission from Messenger Platform API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-permissions

I'm kinda getting lost on Facebook documentation. I'm creating a Messenger Bot. This bot is also integrated with Facebook Graph API and needs to read the users wall so he needs the `user_posts` permission.

My question is: how do I get this permission?

As far as I've understood, there's no real way to get it from the Messenger Platform API. So, I've started looking into the [Login API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/). Here I found out that I can get a `user access token` using an embedded Javascript in a web page to show the Facebook login dialog and letting the user to access their profile.

However this sounds so cumbersome... Is there an easier way to do this?

Thank you for the help.